# How to create a new (date) column based on another column with date in BigQuery for comparison dates?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, google-analytics, comparison

I would like to create a table with the visits (Google Analytics) of a certain date, where I add the visits from the previous year (minus 364 days) to compare these days.

In the first column I have extracted the date and added the totals.visits as sessions (which works). I want to add the date of the previous year, so that I can left join a second table with those dates.

My first output is as follows:

| Date this year | Visits this year |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-01-10 | 100 |
| 2023-01-11 | 200 |

And I'm trying to retrieve this result:

| Date this year | Visits this year | Date last year | Visits last year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-10 | 100 | 2022-01-11 | 150 |
| 2023-01-11 | 200 | 2022-01-12 | 210 |

To add the date of last year, I tried DATE_SUB() with 'date', but it doesn't work. I get the following error;

`No matching signature for function DATE_SUB for argument types: STRING, INTERVAL INT64 DATE_TIME_PART. Supported signatures: DATE_SUB(DATE, INTERVAL INT64 DATE_TIME_PART); DATE_SUB(DATETIME, INTERVAL INT64 DATE_TIME_PART); DATE_SUB(TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL INT64 DATE_TIME_PART)`

```
SELECT
  *
FROM (
  WITH
    variable AS (
    SELECT
      '20230110' AS start_date,
      '20230126' AS end_date ) (
    SELECT
      date,
      SUM(totals.visits) AS sessions,
      DATE_SUB(date, INTERVAL 364 DAY) AS date_lastyear
    FROM
      `my_table`,
      variable
    WHERE
      date >= start_date
      AND date <= end_date
    GROUP BY
      date ) )
```

Does anyone know how to use DATE_SUB() based on a date in a row? OR any other way to get the result I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's debug

`No matching signature for function DATE_SUB for argument types: STRING, INTERVAL INT64 DATE_TIME_PART.`

It says there is no function such as date sub which takes a ***string*** and interval

`Supported signatures: DATE_SUB(DATE, INTERVAL INT64 DATE_TIME_PART)`

The only supported arguments are ***date*** and internal

So the column you are providing as date is a string, it needs to be converted to date so that you can subtract 1 year from it.

you can convert like this -
`SELECT PARSE_DATE("%Y%m%d", date) from my_table`